# Filter the dropdown list for an Enum property in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, enums, propertygrid

I am displaying the properties of an object in a PropertyGrid. One of those properties is an enum. So it is displayed with a combobox editor that lists all of the values of the enum. That's all great, but I need to filter that list of enum values at runtime. I can't just decorate some of the enum values with the Browsable attribute, because which of the values I want to hide will vary. At the moment I'm leaning towards a custom UITypeEditor, but I thought I should check with the smart people first.

Comment: Why the filter?  Are some of them not legal at runtime?  The code for part of the class and the enum would be nice for context.

Comment: Yeah, the set of appropriate enum values changes from moment to moment. I just went with a custom UITypeEditor. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012427/show-only-some-of-the-options-of-an-enumeration/16012557) is an example, though it is solving a slightly different problem (the disallowed enum values do not vary) (and I think the Browsable attribute would [just work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652461/is-it-possible-to-hide-an-enum-value-from-a-propertygrid) without the custom editor anyway). In my case I just add the desired items to the listbox in EditValue().

Comment: Simon's answer wont allow changes "moment to moment".  A TypeConverter might be more appropriate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `TypeConverter` may be all you need, especially if the legal subset "changes from moment to moment".  Given an enum:

```
public enum AnimalSpecies
{
    Canine, Feline, Rodent, Dragon, Unicorn, Robot
}
```

...which is used on a property:

```
public class Animal
{
    ...
    [TypeConverter(typeof(AnimalSpeciesConverter))]
    public AnimalSpecies Species { get; set; }
```

If you decorate the enum, the converter will apply to anything/everything which uses it; on the property, it affects only that.  For the converter, you will want to override `GetStandardValues()`:

```
class AnimalSpeciesConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        Animal test = context.Instance as Animal;

        if (test != null)
            return true;
        else
            return base.GetStandardValuesSupported();
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(AnimalSpecies))
                           .Where(x => !x.StartsWith("Rob")).ToArray();

        return new StandardValuesCollection(names);
    }
}
```

- `GetStandardValuesSupported()` returns true to indicate the `TypeConverter` can and will supply the values.
- `GetStandardValuesExclusive()` indicates that, no the user can't opt to type in their own value.
- `GetStandardValues()` filters the list and returns the new subset.

Result:

[image] **No Robots!**

If the filtering logic is more complex, you might want to let the class instance determine the contents.  Or perhaps you'd just prefer that logic to remain in the class.  To do that I like to use an interface:

```
public interface IValuesProvider
{
    string[] GetValues();
}

public class Animal : IValuesProvider
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [TypeConverter(typeof(AnimalSpeciesConverter))]
    public AnimalSpecies Species { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    ...
    public string[] GetValues()
    {
        List<string> names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(AnimalSpecies)).ToList();

        // your logic here
        if (Value < 10)
            names.Remove(AnimalSpecies.Feline.ToString());
        else if (Value < 50)
            names.Remove(AnimalSpecies.Robot.ToString());

        return names.ToArray();
    }
```

Now, when the PropertyGrid asks for the values, we can get them from the instance:

```
class AnimalSpeciesConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        IValuesProvider test = context.Instance as IValuesProvider;

        if (test != null)
            return true;
        else
            return base.GetStandardValuesSupported();
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        IValuesProvider item = context.Instance as IValuesProvider;
        return new StandardValuesCollection(item.GetValues());
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you can skip the interface and make the `GetValues` method private if you dont like exposing it that wayand get the values by Reflection.  In that case, I might return true for `GetStandardValuesSupported()` only if the method exists.  That way you don't ever have a case where you have returned true for `Get...Supported()` and then not have a way to supply them.

This is dynamic: the values list is refreshed/repolled every time the drop down opens.  Each time you change the `Value`, the drop down list is updated each time it opens.

Comment: very interesting! thanks very much for the thoughtful answer. I do have success also with a custom UITypeEditor, where EditValue() is overridden to grab the appropriate list of values of the moment and add them to the listbox; the drop down list is updated each time it opens. But of course this is better. I totally forgot a TypeConverter has methods to override other than those used to convert types  ;-)

Comment: There are so many ways to do most things, it is hard to keep track which ones will work best.

Comment: Very helpful answer. I made an abstract Enum converter with a dynamic value selection method: public class EnumValueSelectorTypeConverter<TEnum> ... protected virtual bool SelectIsStandardValuesByContextInstance(object contextInstance, out StandardValuesCollection values) ... And a string conversion method: protected virtual IEnumerable<string> ConvertSelectionToStrings(IEnumerable<TEnum> selection) ...